# How to make a specific button appear in one of four places?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a script for a quiz, where there are 4 answers from which only one is correct. I want to make the correct answer appear at random position in one of the 4 buttons, while the rest will be wrong answers. Here's what I've got:

```js
const questions = [
  {name: "question1"}, 
  {name: "question2"}, 
  {name: "question3"}
];

function shuffle(questions) {
  let currentIndex = questions.length,
    randomIndex;
  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;
    [questions[currentIndex], questions[randomIndex]] = [
      questions[randomIndex], questions[currentIndex]
    ];
  }
  return questions;
}

function start() {
  document.getElementById("start").style.display = "none";
  shuffle(questions);
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[0].name;
  document.getElementById("correctanswer").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("wronganswer1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("wronganswer2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("wronganswer3").style.display = "block";
}

function shownextquestion() {
  shuffle(questions);
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[0].name;
}

function correct() {
  document.getElementById("answerstatus") = "Correct Answer!";
}

function incorrect() {
  document.getElementById("answerstatus") = "Wrong Answer";
}
```

```html
<button id="start" onclick="start()">start test</button>
<div id="question"></div>
</br>
<button style="display:none;" id="correctanswer" onclick="shownextquestion();correct()">Correct Answer</button>
</br>
<button style="display:none;" id="wronganswer1" onclick="shownextquestion();incorrect()">Wrong Answer</button>
</br>
<button style="display:none;" id="wronganswer2" onclick="shownextquestion();incorrect()">Wrong Answer</button>
</br>
<button style="display:none;" id="wronganswer3" onclick="shownextquestion();incorrect()">Wrong Answer</button>

</br>
<div id="answerstatus"></div>
```

Basically, I want the "correctanswer" button to appear randomly in one of the four spaces, while the other three are "wronganswer" 1,2 and 3.

Comment: So, what's happening currently when you run it? Please explain the problem to give us somewhere to start.

Comment: @ADyson It doesn't shuffle the buttons...

Comment: I'm not sure I get the problem correctly. You say you want to shuffle the answers but in your code you try to shuffle the questions. Assuming you really want to shuffle the answers to a question, and assuming you had a working `shuffle` function, how do you expect the re-ordering of the buttons to work in the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get the problem correctly. You say you want to shuffle the answers but in your code you try to shuffle the questions.

Assuming you really want to shuffle the answers to a question, I would recommend to choose a different approach:

1. Define an array of `Question` objects providing an array with possible `answers` to the question
2. Write a function which creates the answer buttons dynamically
3. Use a shuffle function to shuffle the answers before rendering

```js
/** All questions with possible answers. */
const questions = [
  {
    name: 'question1',
    text: 'Question 1?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Some wrong answer', correct: false },
      { text: 'Another wrong answer', correct: false },
      { text: 'One more wrong answer', correct: false },
      { text: 'The correct answer', correct: true }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'question2',
    text: 'Question 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Some wrong answer', correct: false },
      { text: 'Another wrong answer', correct: false },
      { text: 'One more wrong answer', correct: false },
      { text: 'The correct answer', correct: true }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    name: 'question3',
    text: 'Question 3?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Some wrong answer', correct: false },
      { text: 'Another wrong answer', correct: false },
      { text: 'One more wrong answer', correct: false },
      { text: 'The correct answer', correct: true }
    ]
  }
];

/** The index of the question currently being displayed */
let questionIndex = 0;

/** Fisher-Yates shuffle function for shuffling arbitrary arrays */
function shuffle(array) {
  const result = [...array];
  for (let i = result.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    let temp = result[i];
    result[i] = result[j];
    result[j] = temp;
  }
  return result;
}

/**
 * Checks for a given question whether the given answer is correct,
 * displays an appropriate message, and shows the button for jumping
 * to the next question.
 */
function checkAnswer(question, answer) {
  document.getElementById('answerstatus').style.display = "block";
  
  const elAnswerStatusText = document.getElementById('answerstatus-text');
  if (answer.correct) {
    elAnswerStatusText.innerHTML = 'Correct answer!';
  }
  else {
    elAnswerStatusText.innerHTML = 'Wrong answer!';
  }
}

/**
 * Creates a DOM representation for a question and its answers.
 * This function first shuffles the possible answers and creates
 * a button element for each, adding an event handler that calls
 * function `checkAnswer()`.
 */
function createQuestion(question) {
  const elQuestion = document.getElementById("question");
  elQuestion.innerHTML = "";
  
  const elQuestionText = elQuestion.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
  elQuestionText.innerHTML = question.text;
  
  
  for (const answer of shuffle(question.answers)) {
    const elButton = elQuestion.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
    elButton.innerHTML = answer.text;
    
    elButton.addEventListener('click', () => checkAnswer(question, answer));
  }
}

function showNextQuestion() {
  questionIndex = (questionIndex + 1) % questions.length;
  document.getElementById('answerstatus').style.display = 'none';
  createQuestion(questions[questionIndex]);
}

function start() {
  document.getElementById("start").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("question").style.display = 'block';
  
  createQuestion(questions[0]);
}
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="start" onclick="start()">start test</button>
  <div id="question" style="display: none">
    <div id="question-text">
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="answerstatus" style="display: none">
    <div id="answerstatus-text">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button onclick="showNextQuestion()">Next Question</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To also shuffle the buttons you can use your `shuffle()` function. For that you need to push the buttons to an array:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.answer');
let button_array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  button_array[i] = buttons[i];
}
```

After shuffling you remove the buttons and append them in the new order. To get this done you could wrap the answer buttons in a container:

```html
<div id="answers">
  <button class="answer" id="correctanswer" onclick="shownextquestion();correct()">Correct Answer</button>
  ...
</div>
```

That container can simply be emptied with `innerHTML = ''` and you can easily append the new ordered buttons to it:

```js
shuffle(button_array);
document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = '';
for (let i = 0; i < button_array.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("answers").append(button_array[i]);
}
```

The container has also the advantage that you can hide and show all answer buttons at once instead of doing that for every single answer button:

```js
function start() {
  document.getElementById("start").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("answers").style.display = "block";
  ...
```

Furthermore are you doing the same thing in `start()` and `shownextquestion()` twice, regarding shuffling and inserting the questions. Therefor it's better to put that code in `shownextquestion()` and call that function in `start()`. Especially because the code gets bigger when you add the shuffling and inserting for the buttons.

**Working example:** (*i exchanged the inline-styles and the br-tags with CSS-styles and toggled in JavaScript a class instead of manipulating the style-attribute*)

```js
const questions = [
  {name: "question1"}, 
  {name: "question2"}, 
  {name: "question3"}
];
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.answer');
let button_array = [];

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  button_array[i] = buttons[i];
}

function shuffle(elements) {
  let currentIndex = elements.length,
    randomIndex;
  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;
    [elements[currentIndex], elements[randomIndex]] = [
      elements[randomIndex], elements[currentIndex]
    ];
  }
  return elements;
}

function start() {
  document.getElementById("start").classList.add("hide");
  document.getElementById("answers").classList.remove("hide");

  shownextquestion();
}

function shownextquestion() {
  shuffle(questions);
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questions[0].name;
  
  shuffle(button_array);
  document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < button_array.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("answers").append(button_array[i]);
  }
}

function correct() {
  document.getElementById("answerstatus").innerHTML = "Correct Answer!";
}

function incorrect() {
  document.getElementById("answerstatus").innerHTML = "Wrong Answer";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

button {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="start" onclick="start()">start test</button>
<div id="question"></div>

<div id="answers" class="hide">
  <button class="answer" id="correctanswer" onclick="shownextquestion(); correct()">Correct Answer</button>
  <button class="answer" id="wronganswer1" onclick="shownextquestion(); incorrect()">Wrong Answer</button>
  <button class="answer" id="wronganswer2" onclick="shownextquestion(); incorrect()">Wrong Answer</button>
  <button class="answer" id="wronganswer3" onclick="shownextquestion(); incorrect()">Wrong Answer</button>
</div>

<div id="answerstatus"></div>
```